# How do you access constructors variables?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have a "class" within Javascript with a variable assigned in the constructor. I also use prototype to store variables/methods:

```
var MyClass = function() 
{ 
    this.age = 100;
};

MyClass.prototype.name = "John";
MyClass.prototype.getAge = function() { return this.age};

alert(MyClass.prototype.name); //Alerts John
alert(MyClass.age); //undefined as expected
alert(MyClass.prototype.getAge()); //undefined??
```

So from what I can tell, there is no way I can access the constructor variables that are stored within MyClass unless I create an object from the Class:

```
var theClass = new MyClass();
alert(theClass.age);
alert(theClass.getAge());​
```

Both alerts will return the age correctly.

So to reiterate, can I access the constructor variables directly from the MyClass without needing to create a variable?

Comment: why would you avoid to use a variable?

Comment: @Nealbo, You need to use like as static properties?

Comment: Regarding `alert(MyClass.prototype.getAge()); //undefined??`: It would try to access `MyClass.prototype.age` which does not exist. Inside the constructor `this` refers to an empty object with *inherits* from `MyClass.prototype`, so `age` will *never* be assigned to `MyClass.prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The variable `age` in your example is *created* when the constructor function runs; therefore it's not going to be available until you run the function.

Answer (score 2):

> So from what I can tell, there is no way I can access the constructor variables that are stored within MyClass unless I create an object from the Class

Correct. They are assigned in the function body. They won't exist until the function is executed.

> So to reiterate, can I access the constructor variables directly from the MyClass without needing to create a variable?

No.